# getting duplicate records when using @ManyToMany annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i got 3 tables: 1.moduls with atribue id , 2.variant with attribute id  and 3.moduls_variant with attributes moduls_id, variant_id.

I got these tables mapped into two classes:

Moduls

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "moduls")
public class Moduls
    {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id")...
   }
```

Variant

```
@Table(name = "variant")
@Entity
public class Variant{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id", unique = true)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade =    CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "moduls_variant",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "variant_id") ,
    inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "moduls_id") )
    private Set<Moduls> modulsSet = new HashSet<Moduls>();...
    }
```

And there goes my problem.
Lets say that i got in table moduls items with IDs 1,2 and3.
In table variant item with id 1.
And finally in table moduls_variant 3 rows:

1|1

1|2

1|3

Problem is that now when i want to get all items (I should get only 1 item) from table variant by using:

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Variant.class);
getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(detachedCriteria);
```

I get three times the same object from table variant (with the same ID)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you set the `@ManyToMany` association with `FetchType.EAGER`, which returns a cartesian result.
You can either, remove the eager fetching to fallback to default lazy initialization or add the following transformer:

```
detachedCriteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Comment: Why would anyone implement the `@ManyToMany` to return cartesian result? Did he hate the mankind or what?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post, but it came up on my search so here's an alternate solution to Julien's accepted answer.  You can keep the EAGER fetch, just add this:

`@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)`

annotation to get around the cartesian result.  Obviously there will be performance impacts so be cautious where you use it.

End result will look like:

```
@Table(name = "variant")
@Entity
public class Variant{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id", unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "moduls_variant",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "variant_id") ,
        inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "moduls_id") )
    private Set<Moduls> modulsSet = new HashSet<Moduls>();

     ...
    }
```